# Imagemin in Electron App Not Compressing Images

Tags: node.js, electron, imagemin

I'm trying to compress a single PNG image in an Electron application using this code

```
  const files = await imagemin([filePath], {
    destination: destinationPath,
    plugins: [
      imageminPngquant({
        quality: [0.2, 0.4],
        speed: 1
      })
    ]
  });
  debuglog(files);
```

filePath contains a full path to a PNG file, e.g.

```
C:\Users\name\Downloads\images\needle.png
```

This file does exist, and the path is correct: when I put the same path into Windows explorer, the png opens.

destinationPath contains a path to the same directory in which the .png file resides (in other words, I want to overwrite the original file), e.g.

```
C:\Users\name\Downloads\images
```

When I run this, the original file remains unchanged, and the variable "files" returned by the function call contains an empty array.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to get debug output that tells me what exactly imagemin is doing?

**Update**: here's a concrete example. The code looks like this:

```
  console.log("compressPNG");
  console.log(filePath);
  console.log(path);
  var files = await imagemin([filePath], {
    destination: path,
    plugins: [
      imageminPngquant({
        quality: [0.2, 0.4],
        speed: 1
      })
    ]
  });
  console.log(files);
```

This produces the following log output:

[image: Log output from running the image compression code]

Comment: Could you `console.log()` the two paths just before the code you posted? The backslashes may be a problem.

Comment: Also, for the future, it would be helpful to include a [example] in your post. So far, I don't see a connection to Electron at all, so the example could be very succinct. Still, it's part of the OP's job to make helping them as easy as possible (and will often prevent entire questions from being asked).

Comment: Thank you, snwflk, I've added an example that shows actual log output for the paths.
I'm not sure how to create a reproducible example of an Electron app, and I'm not sure whether there is a connection to Electron at all, but since it happens in an Electron app, I thought I should provide that context. I'll try to come up with something reproducible that I can post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This bug report](https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin/issues/352) indicates that you need to convert backward slashes (`\`) to forward slashes (`/`).

According to one of the commenters, the package `globby` that `imagemin` relies on expects filepaths with forward slashes (`/`) as the delimiter.

Here is a complete example:

```js
const imagemin = require("imagemin");
const imageminPngquant = require("imagemin-pngquant");

let input_path = "C:\\path\\to\\file.png";
let output_dir = "C:\\output\\directory";

// Replace backward slashes with forward slashes      <-- Option A
input_path = input_path.replace(/\\/g, "/");
output_dir = output_dir.replace(/\\/g, "/");

(async () => {
  var files = await imagemin([input_path], {
    destination: output_dir,
    // glob: false,                                   <-- Option B
    plugins: [
      imageminPngquant({
        quality: [0.2, 0.4],
        speed: 1
      })
    ]
  });
  console.log(files);
})();
```

Alternatively, setting `glob: false` should also help accept Windows filepaths, as it circumvents use of the `globby` module.

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much, I was losing my mind.